# jQuery hide only works when toggling fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to toggle hiding "myDIV" with jQuery.
Works perfect on mobile, but when pressing the button on desktop
only works if you toggle fullscreen after presing the button, otherwhise
it doesn't. Anyone had this problem before?

Heres a link to the site:

https://mkt.partners/analytical/draft.html

the button is on line 616

```
<a onclick="javascript:toggler('myDIV');" class="btn btn-primary lookbook-action"><b>Ver más.</b></a>
```

the div im trying to hide is in line 618

```
<div id="myDIV" class="hidden">
```

CSS class "hidden" just hides the div

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
     display:none;
}
    </style>
```

and my script is in line 1460

```
    <script>
function toggler(divId) {
  $("#" + divId).toggle("slow");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide some code to make this problem reproducible in order to make it easier for others to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: i provided a link with the code 

https://mkt.partners/analytical/draft.html

Comment: I know, but it is not easy to see for others what button has the problem and what specific code it uses.

Comment: you're totally right! sorrry, im new here, i provided more details, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Hi, What is the CSS of the hidden class?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  .hidden {
     display:none;
}
 </style>

Comment: This isn't related to your question at all, but I feel like I should point out that you should probably have that `<a>` tag be a `<button>` tag instead — semantics are very important for accessibility, and it's not a link to anywhere. Cheers, welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery's documenation:

> With no parameters, the `.toggle()` method simply toggles the visibility of elements [...]
>   The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no animation, by changing the CSS display property.

This means that JQuery is directly modifying the **inline** style attribute.

*Your* problem comes from the fact that you have this item's `display` property set to `none` in *another location* (your CSS). So, your button is hidden 100% of the time, regardless of what JQuery does.

It's like you've got something covered with a curtain, and then try and hide it again by covering it with another curtain... only to pull back the second one and wonder why your object isn't visible — it's still covered by the first curtain!

---

Get rid of the extra CSS (the `hidden` class) and let JQuery deal with the hiding.

```js
function toggler(divId) {
  $("#" + divId).toggle("slow");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDIV" style="background-color: red; width: 5em; height: 5em;"></div>

<!-- Use a button, not an anchor, since this isn't a link -->
<button onclick="toggler('myDIV');" class="btn btn-primary lookbook-action">
  <!-- <b> tags are deprecated, use strong instead -->
  <strong>Ver más.</strong>
</button>
```

The whole "this works on desktop but only if you fullscreen, and it always works on mobile" thing makes me think that you've got this CSS mishap behind some media queries or something.

I tested the live link you gave, simply turning off `display: none` in my DevTools in the `.hidden` class fixed the issue, and the *Ver más* button successfully hides the `div`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! the button is properly working now, but i have another problem.
I need the div to be hidden by default, that's why i added extra CSS. do you know how to invert the default state of the toggle?

Comment: @SoporteMercodigital If that's the case, what I would probably do is, isntead of using `.toggle()` or `.hide()`, I would keep the CSS class, and instead use JQuery to toggle that class itself. Use [`$('#' + divID').toggleClass('hidden')`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). :-)

Comment: i tried doint it that way and now the button doesn't work at all T.T
halp

Comment: the method you mentioned is currently uploaded in the original link

Comment: @SoporteMercodigital In your current example, you've got `$(div.myDIV)`. That will select based on the *class* `myDIV`. You want `div#myDIV`.

Comment: Ok, now we're back to the start, it works on mobile or windowed, but not on fullscreen.

Comment: https://mkt.partners/analytical/draft.html check it out, its online

Comment: @SoporteMercodigital Doesn't look like you've changed it to me. I still see `$( "div.myDIV" ).toggleClass('hidden');` in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: how about now? i have it div#myDIV and works only if i toggle fullscreen after pressing the button